# Compile Virtual Keyboard for Qt WebAssembly

Tags: c++, qt, qml, webassembly, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to compile the virtual keyboard project example from `QtCreator` in `WebAssembly`.

To compile for wasm library have to be linked statically. According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html#static-builds):

> Static builds
>
> The virtual keyboard can be built and linked statically against the
> application. This implies that Qt is also built statically (using the
> -static option in the configure command line).
>
> Static builds of the virtual keyboard are enabled by adding
> CONFIG+=static to the qmake command line and then rebuilding.
>
> Some third party modules used by the virtual keyboard are always built
> as shared libraries. These modules are Hunspell and Lipi Toolkit.

Said so, I'm trying to compile with

```
mkdir buildwasm && cd buildwasm
/opt/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake .. CONFIG+=static CONFIG+=disable-hunspell && make -j8
```

But somehow keyboard is not statically linked and I receive this error

```
wasm-ld: error: initial memory too small, 18699856 bytes needed
shared:ERROR: ...
```

am I missing something or it's a kind of a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-s TOTAL_MEMORY=32MB` compiler flag to preset a size at emcc link time.
Related question: [wasm-ld: error: initial memory too small, 18317952 bytes needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595167/wasm-ld-error-initial-memory-too-small-18317952-bytes-needed)

There is a default limit setting, set to: 16777216
https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L171